# Get Average of most Similar Colors in color ArrayList with unknown size

Tags: java, arraylist, colors, average

I'm trying to create a denoiser in Java and now I'm at the state of actually creating the denoiser. The denoiser already knows what is noise and what isn't.

Now I'm trying to come up with a function that gives me the average color of an ArrayList with the size between 0 and 8. I know how to do this in general but I don't know how to ignore "extreme values (For example, if I have 3 similar Colors in the ArrayList (for example 3 similar red) and a color that is completely different (for example dark blue), the "extreme value" should be ignored because for example, the average of those 3 reds is 0xFD010B and if you include the dark blue, the average turns into 0xFD01FA, which is a "completely different color".

How can I write a function that can give me the average color of an undefined amount of similar colors and ignore the "less similar ones?

**Note that I am not allowed to import 3rd party libraries and I am using "pure java" so I can't import gradle or maven dependencies**

Comment: You would need some form of distance function which will calculate a distance between two colors then calculate a weighted average with the weight being `1 / distance`. This way very distant colors will only have a small weight and therefore have less impact on the average being computed. One distance function might be to calulate an absolute/ squared difference for each of the three rgb channels and divide that by 3. `(255, 255, 0)` and `(250, 250, 5)` would therefore be (absolute difference) `(5 + 5 + 5) / 3 = 5`.

Comment: Also [(weighted) moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) might be helpful.